# Efficient sum / group by query in Rails using SQLite

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 and would like to get totals by month for a numeric field. Models look like:

```
    # Table name: accounts
    #  id               :integer         not null, primary key
    #  created_at       :datetime
    #  updated_at       :datetime

    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :debitentries, :class_name => "Posting", :foreign_key => "debitaccount_id"
    has_many :creditentries, :class_name => "Posting", :foreign_key => "creditaccount_id"


    # Table name: postings
    #  id               :integer         not null, primary key
    #  voucherdate      :date
    #  debitaccount_id  :integer
    #  creditaccount_id :integer
    #  euroamount       :decimal(, )

    Class Postings  < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :debitaccount, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "debitaccount_id"
    belongs_to :creditaccount, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "creditaccount_id"
```

My objective is to query the postings where the voucherdate < 12 month and get a total euroamount-sum of debitentries/creditentries for each account number, i.e.

```
    Account.id| Feb 2012 | Jan 2012 | Dec 2011 | ... | Mar 2011
    ------------------------------------------------------------
       1      |   233.87 | 123.72   | ...      |     | sum(euroamount)
       2      |    ...   |          |          |     |
```

I think I will need two queries (one for sume of debitentries and one for creditentries), but I think it will be much more efficient than using rails-functions. Can anyone help me how such a query would have to look like? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's SQL to get credit and debit sums by month for each account:

```
Select accounts.id, 
strftime('%B %Y', voucherdate) month,
sum(credits.euroamount) total_credits,
sum(debits.euroamount) total_debits
from accounts
join postings as credits
  on accounts.id = creditaccount_id
join postings as debits
  on accounts.id = debitaccount_id
group by accounts.id, strftime('%B %Y', voucherdate)
```

The result will look like this:

```
id     | month          | total_credits | total_debits
-------------------------------------------------------
1      | January 2011   | 243.12        | 123.12
1      | February 2011  | 140.29        | 742.22
1      | March 2011     | 673.19        | 238.11
2      | January 2011   | 472.23        | 132.14
2      | February 2011  | 365.34        | 439.99
```

To execute arbitrary sql in rails:

```
account_id_hash = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("Select accounts.id from accounts")
```

From here you'll need to cross-tab or pivot the data into the format you need using old-fashioned ruby code. If you need help with that feel free to post a new question.